# Compile single c++ file to exe in VC++ 2010 Express with customized include path

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I am trying to compile single cpp file in VC++ 2010 Express, instead of the whole project. So, I noticed that I can do ctrl + f7 to compile single files into .obj file. However, I do not know how to link it to .exe file, without doing this on the whole project in the IDE.

I do realize that this is fairly simple in command line, however for cmd it is hard to include all the project-specific properties. For example, I have been using the boost lib and I have to add that to path if I am using the command line. So, an IDE solution would be preferred.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add another project to the solution, add just that file and the required headers, and hit compile?

Comment: @MicroVirus Thanks! That'll definitely work. I was wondering whether there will be a more light-weight solution though... Or am I too greedy?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759312/560648 (as it happens, despite the version differential)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you sir... This seems to be the right thing to do. Mine is a duplicate.